# Get Size of grouped properties in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, list, count

How can I do this?

I have one `ArrayList<ErrorDetails>` where `error details` is POJO having `errorCode` and `errorMessage` properties.

Data within this error list can be --

```
 [999, "Hello"]
 [111, "Hello"]
 [999, "Hello"]
 [111, "Hello"]
 [999, "Hello"]
 [999, "Hello"]
 [456, "Hello"]
 [456, "Hello"]
 [999, "Hello"]
```

I want to have a result where I get a list with 3 items having,

```
[unique error code, no of occurence of this error code in previous list].
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your `List` and put the error code as `key`s in `Map` with value as occurrences

Code:

```
    List<ErroCodeMessage> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    //... add ErroCodeMessages
    Map<Integer, Integer> stat = new HashMap<>();

    for (ErroCodeMessage error : errors) {
        if (stat.get(error.getErrorCode()) != null) {
            stat.put(error.getErrorCode(), stat.get(error.getErrorCode()) + 1);
        } else {
            stat.put(error.getErrorCode(), 1);
        }
    }
```

ErrorCodeMessage POJO class

```
class ErroCodeMessage {

    private int errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public ErroCodeMessage(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: this answer is wrong, at the end it returns only size 1 for all errorcodes

Answer (score 1):

You can group and count with Java 8 featue `Stream` like:

```
Map<Integer, Long> mapping = list.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(ErrorDetails::getErrorCode, counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the key exists or not. If it doesn't exist, you add the key and 1 as a value. If it does exist, you increment the keys's value of 1.